# Create a function/for loop/map/lappy to run multiple seeded LDA models and extract the thetas

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, lda

I know that LDA models (including seeded LDA models) are inherently inconsistent, because of the random element in how they commence.

Therefore, I want to run my LDA model n number of times, each with a different `set.seed()`, look at the average theta for each document, and then choose the model that is closest to that average.

So, this is what I do once:

```
require(quanteda)

data("data_corpus_moviereviews", package = "quanteda.textmodels")
corp <- head(data_corpus_moviereviews, 500)
toks <- tokens(corp, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE, remove_number = TRUE)
dfmt <- dfm(toks) %>%
    dfm_remove(stopwords('en'), min_nchar = 2) %>%
    dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 0.90, termfreq_type = "quantile",
             max_docfreq = 0.1, docfreq_type = "prop")

dict <- dictionary(list(people = c("family", "couple", "kids"),
                        space = c("alien", "planet", "space"),
                        moster = c("monster*", "ghost*", "zombie*"),
                        war = c("war", "soldier*", "tanks"),
                        crime = c("crime*", "murder", "killer")))

set.seed(23)
slda23 <- textmodel_seededlda(dfmt, dict, residual = TRUE, min_termfreq = 10)

theta_23 <- as_tibble(slda23$theta)
theta_23$id <- seq(1, 500, by = 1)
theta_23_long <- theta_23 %>% pivot_longer(-c(id), names_to= "topic", values_to = "seed_23") 
head(theta_23_long, 20) 
# A tibble: 20 x 3
      id topic  seed_23
   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
 1     1 people 0.124  
 2     1 space  0.00538
 3     1 moster 0.0699 
 4     1 war    0.328  
 5     1 crime  0.188  
 6     1 other  0.285  
 7     2 people 0.0472 
 8     2 space  0.651  
 9     2 moster 0.0849 
10     2 war    0.0660 
11     2 crime  0.123  
12     2 other  0.0283 
13     3 people 0.00685
14     3 space  0.0479 
15     3 moster 0.0205 
16     3 war    0.651  
17     3 crime  0.116  
18     3 other  0.158  
19     4 people 0.00625
20     4 space  0.00625
```

I want to do that n number of further times, each with a different `set.seed()`, so my final tibble has a new column for each of my models, with the `set.seed()` number as the column title.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

lets call your result frame LDA_results. Then it's pretty easy to just

```
LDA_results <- data.frame(seed = integer(), theta = double())
for (i in 1:num_iterations) {
  set.seed(23 + i) # just alter the seed in the for loop, you could do whatever you like

  slda23 <- textmodel_seededlda(dfmt, dict, residual = TRUE, min_termfreq = 10)
  theta_23 <- as_tibble(slda23$theta)
  theta_23$id <- seq(1, 500, by = 1)
  theta_23_long <- theta_23 %>% pivot_longer(-c(id), names_to= "topic", values_to = "seed_23")  

  # I'm assuming here that seed_23 is the theta for each word, 
  # but you have to check that yourself
  LDA_results[nrow(LDA_results) + 1,] <- c(23 + i, mean(theta_23_long$seed_23))
}
```

Comment: I get this error ```Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "seed", value = 24) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0```

Comment: My mistake. I edited it such that now the values obtained in the loop are appended in the last row. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.  That gets me most of the way there!